# Generating up to X number of values based on a formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

```css
table,th,td { border: 1px solid #ccc; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; }
th { background: #eee; }
th, td { padding: 5px 10px; }
th
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>A</th>
<th>B</th>
<th>C</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>1</th>
<td>donkey</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>donkey; donkey-2; donkey-3; donkey-4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>2</th>
<td>cow</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>cow; cow-2; cow-3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>3</th>
<td>chicken</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>chicken; chicken-2; chicken-3; chicken-4; chicken-5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'm looking to auto-generate column C, based on values in column A and B. The number of outputs in column C essentially depends on the value in B (which can as high as 10).

Note please that the first instance of the result is without a -number at the end.

Is this possible in Excel?

Answer (score 1):

You tagged `Excel-Formula` so try the below:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("; ",1,A1&"-"&ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,B1))),"-1","",1)
```

The use of `Instance` parameter within `SUBSTITUTE` would ensure that only the first occurence of `-1` would get replaced with `""`.

It's also easily done through VBA.

> **Note:** It's an array formula and needs to be confirmed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

As @JdV mentioned, this can also be achieved in VBA:

```
Sub sAddValue()
    Dim lngLast As Long
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    Dim strOutput As String
    lngLast = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For lngRow = 1 To lngLast
        If Cells(lngRow, 2) = 1 Then
            Cells(lngRow, 3) = Cells(lngRow, 1)
        Else
            strOutput = Cells(lngRow, 1)
            For lngLoop1 = 2 To Cells(lngRow, 2)
                strOutput = strOutput & ";" & Cells(lngRow, 1) & "-" & lngLoop1
            Next lngLoop1
            Cells(lngRow, 3) = strOutput
        End If
    Next lngRow
End Sub
```

Regards,